# Is the Intuit processor active/functional?

Tags: extension, payment-processor

I have a question from a group that uses Intuit with their POS system and were wondering if they could integrate their CiviCRM payments directly into that same account.

I see there is a [Wiki page from 2013](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Setting+up+Intuit+QuickBooks+Payment+Processor+for+CiviCRM) about setting up Intuit payments, but I can't even get the extension to install on CiviCRM 4.6.8. (I copied the .zip file [from Github](https://github.com/webaccess/CiviCRM-Intuit-Payment-Processor) and unpacked in the CiviCRM Extensions directory but it doesn't show in the Extensions list, even after refreshing. I assume this means the extension is stale / not functional with a recent version of CiviCRM)

Is anyone using Intuit or should I consider this a lost cause and go to plan B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pre-civix extension - which probably makes it one of the first extensions, period.

I tried building a civix extension and dropping the files in from Github, but it isn't showing up as a payment processor option.

That said - the code doesn't look like it's in such bad shape.  A little bit of love would probably get this functional.

Comment: Thanks, @Jon G! I will see if they want to use this enough to devote a little bit of extra time/money into cleaning this up. Otherwise they may opt for plan B (an existing payment processor).

Answer (score 2):

Just got done fixing a civi install that uses this. It doesn't exactly install like an extension. According to the [wiki page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Setting+up+Intuit+QuickBooks+Payment+Processor+for+CiviCRM) on how to set this up, files need to be copied over like so from a cloned git to civicrm module:

CRM/Core/Payment/IntuitQuickbooks.php >> civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/IntuitQuickbooks.php

CRM/Event/Payment/IntuitQuickbooks.php >> civicrm/CRM/Event/Payment/IntuitQuickbooks.php

CRM/Contribute/Payment/IntuitQuickbooks.php >> civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Payment/IntuitQuickbooks.php