# Quickbooks Merchant Services Payment Processor extension

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, payment-processor, recurring-contributions

Anybody know if the Intuit Quickbooks Merchant Services Payment Processor extension is still in the works?

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=15856.0

or if this will work with civi 4.6x, I see it's been used on 4.X as recently as 2015.

[Is the Intuit processor active/functional?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6670/is-the-intuit-processor-active-functional)

thanks.

Comment: I dont know whether it works. Possibly the quickest way is to try to install it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious if anyone knows if this extension mentioned here: [Is the Intuit processor active/functional?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6670/is-the-intuit-processor-active-functional) is still working now that Quickbooks changed to the Quickbooks Merchant Services.

Any help thoughts would be appreciated.